# How to skip empty option value in foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a `foreach` loop inside there is another `foreach` loop.As in screenshot there are repeating option with empty values.I just want to skip empty values.

[image]

```
foreach ($se as $de){
    if (empty($de)) {
       continue;
    }
    foreach ($scores as $oppt):
        if (empty($oppt)) {
            continue;
        }

        echo $de."<br/>";
        // print_r (explode(" ",$de));

        $warranty = 'PPI';
        $att = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($de);
        if(!empty($att)){
            $avi = $att->getSource()->getOptionId($oppt);

            $product->setData($de, $avi);
            echo $avi."<br/>";
        }        
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the contents actually matches what is classed as `empty`?

Comment: `<br/>` is printing empy lines. remove it and you won't find new lines

Comment: Referring back to my first comment, what if you did `empty(trim($x))`?

Comment: script47 empty is working fine just removing empty rows.but i have problem of repeating rows.

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter to remove the empty values from array before loop.